# is * mandatory while doing typedef of a function pointer?

Tags: c++, c, function, function-pointers, typedef

I came to this question when I wrote one "unintended" piece of code, and compiled it successfully and got the desired behavior. Later I noted the oddity of the change and realized that I used a complete reverse order of doing typedef of function pointers. Now I am confused if the "unintended" mistake is actually syntactically correct.

Usual convention:

```
typedef void* (*_malloc_fail_handler_ptr)(int) __attribute__ ((unused));
_malloc_fail_handler_ptr _malloc_fail_handler = NULL;
```

My "unintended" code:

```
typedef void* (_malloc_fail_handler_ptr)(int) __attribute__ ((unused));
_malloc_fail_handler_ptr* _malloc_fail_handler = NULL;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's correct syntax. For the 2nd case, the type of `_malloc_fail_handler_ptr` is function, not function pointer. Then the type of `_malloc_fail_handler_ptr*` is pointer to function. So for both the 1st and 2nd cases, the type of the variable `_malloc_fail_handler` is the same.

Comment: yes, though the name should be changed to _malloc_fail_handler_func or something so the name is consistent with what it is :). (nit picking)

Comment: This is in fact rather useful since it allows the functions implementing the interface to be explicitly declared as doing so, as in `extern malloc_fail_handler_t implementor;`.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with the second one is the naming:

```
typedef void* (*_malloc_fail_handler_ptr)(int) __attribute__ ((unused));
```

There, `_malloc_fail_handler_ptr` is a **pointer to** function taking an `int` and returning `void*`.

```
typedef void* (_malloc_fail_handler_ptr)(int) __attribute__ ((unused));
```

Here, `_malloc_fail_handler_ptr` is a function taking an `int` and returning `void*`. It's a function type, not a pointer type. So the suffix `_ptr` is misleading. But like any (in C++, non-reference) type, you can always write `T*` to get a pointer to `T`, so this works.

---

Simplifying everything to avoid the awkward function syntax, your question boils down to:

```
typedef int* ptr;
ptr x = NULL;
```

versus:

```
typedef int ptr;
ptr* x = NULL;
```

Both are syntactically fine, but the second one is pretty misleadingly named.